# Android multiple dialogs under tabactivity showDialog(0)

Tags: android, dialog, multidimensional-array, tabactivity, buttonclick

I wanted to create a multiple Activitiy under tab dialog. But the problem is that when I press the button, I get the following error: and apps from bases.

> 06-18 19:57:06.444 E / AndroidRuntime (1061): $
>   android.view.WindowManager BadTokenException: Unable to add window -
>   token $ android.app.LocalActivityManager Local Activity Record @
>   44f6a3e8 is not valid, is your activity running?

Program is to **showDialog(0)**, and is accurate. I have searched long time but unfortunately I could not find the answer. Please help.
How can I display a multiple Tabactivitiy dialogue. ?

**Tabs Activity :**

```
public class main extends TabActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 Resources res = getResources();
 TabHost tb = getTabHost();
 TabHost.TabSpec spec;
 Intent inten;

 //tourism tab
 inten = new Intent().setClass(this, tum_yemekler.class);
 spec = tb.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tüm Yemekler",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hotel))
 .setContent(inten);
 tb.addTab(spec);

 //hotel tab
 inten = new Intent().setClass(this, contactgroupeinkaufliste.class);
 spec = tb.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Yemek Bul",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.wisata))
 .setContent(inten);
 tb.addTab(spec);

 //mall tab
 inten = new Intent().setClass(this, gunun_menusu.class);
 spec = tb.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Günün Menüsü",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mall))
 .setContent(inten);
 tb.addTab(spec);

 //restourant tab
 inten = new Intent().setClass(this, yardim.class);
 spec = tb.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Yardım",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.restoran))
 .setContent(inten);
 tb.addTab(spec);

 tb.setCurrentTab(0);
 }
}
```

**ActivityGroup :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class contactgroupeinkaufliste extends ActivityGroup {
    View rootView;

    public static   contactgroupeinkaufliste  ContactGroupEinkaufliste_;
    sayilar ddsayilar ;
    private  ArrayList<View> history1;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     this.history1 = new ArrayList<View>();
     ContactGroupEinkaufliste_ = this;
  View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CitiesActivity", new
            Intent(this,secimliyemek_main.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

// Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
replaceView(view);

 }

public void replaceView(View v) {

    // Adds the old one to history
     history1.add(v);

    // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
    setContentView(v);
}



public void back() {  
    if(history1.size() > 0) {  
    history1.remove(history1.size()-1);
        if(history1.size()<=0){
            finish();
        }else{
            setContentView(history1.get(history1.size()-1));
        }
    }else {  
        finish();  
    }  
}

@Override  
public void onBackPressed() {  
    contactgroupeinkaufliste.ContactGroupEinkaufliste_.back();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    contactgroupeinkaufliste.ContactGroupEinkaufliste_.back();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}


}
```

**Activity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class secimliyemek_main extends Activity {
  public static   secimliyemek_main  secimliyemek_main_;

        public static sayilar sayilarr;
        public static String  baslik  ;
        public static bilgideposu arraylistesi;
        public static String [] baharat  ;
        public static String [] option;
        public static boolean[] _selections  ;
        public static LinkedList<String> malzemeler =new  LinkedList<String>();
        protected Button Button_sebzeler;
    protected Button Button_baharatlar;
    protected Button Button_baklagiller;

    @Override
    public void    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.secimliyemek_main);



            Button_sebzeler = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.sebzeler );
            Button_sebzeler.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler_sebzeler()  );
            Button_baharatlar = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.baharat );
            Button_baharatlar.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler_baharat()  );
            Button_baklagiller = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.baklagil);
            Button_baklagiller.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler_baklagiller()  );

       Button yemek_bul =(Button)findViewById(R.id.yemek_bul);

        yemek_bul.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
      View view1 = contactgroupeinkaufliste.ContactGroupEinkaufliste_.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("secimliyemek_liste", 
              new Intent("com.faqih.tutorialtab.SECIMLIYEMEK_LISTE")
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

          // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
      contactgroupeinkaufliste.ContactGroupEinkaufliste_.replaceView(view1);

         }
       });


    }


    public class ButtonClickHandler_sebzeler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick( View view ) {

              option =arraylistesi.sebzeler;
              baslik = "Sebzeler";

              boolean[] _selectionss =  new boolean[ option.length ];
              _selections=_selectionss;

              Button_sebzeler = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.sebzeler );
       //-------------- error comes from here -----------------????
              showDialog(0); 

         }
    }


    public class ButtonClickHandler_baharat implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick( View view ) {

          option =arraylistesi.baharatlar;
          baslik = "Baharatlar";

          boolean[] _selectionss =  new boolean[ option.length ];
          _selections=_selectionss;

          Button_baharatlar = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.baharat );
          showDialog(2);

               }
    }


    public class ButtonClickHandler_baklagiller implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick( View view ) {

          option =arraylistesi.baklagiller;
          baslik = "Baklagiller";

          boolean[] _selectionss =  new boolean[ option.length ];
          _selections=_selectionss;

          Button_baklagiller = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.baklagil );
          showDialog(3);
     }
 }



    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) 
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Enter Holla message");
        EditText hollaMessage = new EditText(this);
        dialog.setView(hollaMessage);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        List result = new ArrayList();
        }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dismissDialog(0); } });
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
        return alert;
     }



    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected )
        {
            printSelectedPlanets(selected,clicked);
            Toast.makeText(secimliyemek_main.this, clicked +"  "+selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked )
        {


            switch( clicked )  
            {  
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:  
                    closeContextMenu();  
                    break;  

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:  
                    break;  
            }  
            }  

    }

    protected void printSelectedPlanets(boolean clickedv, int clickedsv){

            if(clickedv == true){
            malzemeler.add(option[ clickedsv ]);
             Toast.makeText(secimliyemek_main.this, "eklenen: "+option[ clickedsv ] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(clickedv== false){
            malzemeler.remove(option[ clickedsv]);
             Toast.makeText(secimliyemek_main.this, "cikarilan: "+option[ clickedsv ] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        contactgroupeinkaufliste.ContactGroupEinkaufliste_.  back();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } 
 }
```

Comment: got answer ? i am also searching for the same :(

Comment: me to searching for the same